# deploying nextjs app to elastic beanstalk

Tags: reactjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, next.js

Having trouble deploying to elastic beanstalk production

I compressed a package.json, next.config.js, .next folder into a zip and uploaded it to elastic beanstalk to deploy.

My error logs tell me this:
Cannot find module '@zeit/next-sass', the thing is I put this in dev dependencies, but isn't this a dev dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-sass#installation) it should be installed a prod (not dev) dependency

```
npm install --save @zeit/next-sass node-sass
```